# 421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection

Tags: linux, ftp

I have a Centos7 VM using Linux sitting on my Windows 10 Laptop and am trying to ftp some files from a server using the command line at this point.
The process of ftp'ing works when getting the files from the server to the Windows Laptop but when I attempt to ftp to the vm I get the 421 error.

```
> ftp> open 10.10.10.10
Connected to 10.10.10.10.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (10.10.10.10): userid
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> asc
200 Switching to ASCII mode.
ftp> passive
Passive mode off.
ftp> get filename.stg
local: filename.stg remote: filename.stg
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
```

I turned passive mode off ( I believe this changes it to active mode) because this is what I was advised to do by the administrator to get filezilla to work - which it does from the laptop to the server.  Regardless, if I have passive mode off or on I still get the same error.
I have stopped/disabled the firewalld and run the same code but got the same result and have also added the port 21/tcp to the public and trusted zones in firewalld thinking that the firewall was stopping the file being transferred.
The VM is using two adapters - host only adapter and NAT.
Something on the VM is blocking the process but not sure where to shine the spotlight.